# sum quantity of dictionaries in array

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, sum-of-digits

I have a NSArray containing a list of NSDictionary. Like:

```
NSArray *array = ...;
NSDictionary *item = [array objectAtIndex:0];
NSLog (@"quantity: %@", [item objectForKey: @"quantity"]);
```

How can I sum all the quantities contained in all dictionaries of the array?

Answer (score 8):

I think you can try [KVC](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html.)

```
NSMutableArray *goods = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSString *key = @"quantity";

[goods addObject:@{key:@(1)}];

[goods addObject:@{key:@(2)}];

[goods addObject:@{key:@(3)}];

NSNumber *sum = [goods valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.quantity"];
NSLog(@"sum = %@", sum);
```

Comment: You're updating the same dictionary and adding it 3 times, so the sum will be 9, when you'd expect 6. You need to create a new dictionary in each case, like `[goods addObject:@{@"quantity": @1}];`

Answer (score 2):

If you call valueForKey: on an array it gives you an array of all the values for that key, so [array valueForKey:@"quantity"] will give you an array which you can loop over and sum all the values.

Comment: It's a so great way to get the array from each dictionary in the original array! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
NSMutableArray *quantityArray = [item objectForKey: @"quantity"];
int total =0;
for(int i=0;i<[quantityArray count];i++)
{
  total+= [quantityArray objectAtIndex:i];
}
```